# how to catch all url variables

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?!public).*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) index.php?c=$1&a=$2 [NC]
```

How can i modify it that it could support more variables like: `/user/login&d=example&e=example2`, now it just ignores the part after `/user/login...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?!public).*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) index.php?c=$1&a=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC]
```

Notice the `&%{QUERY_STRING}`, which will add the rest of the query string to index.php

Answer (score 0):

[have a look on this tutorial](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html) should solve your problem